# HTML submit a post inside another form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `PHP` template which puts my main page div inside a form. I do not like it but it is not my choice.
I need to add a button that submit a `post` to `action2.php` page instead of `action1.php`. The problem is the second button, submits the combination of field of both forms to `action1.php` instead of only sending information of form 2 to `action2.php`.

I am aware that `<form>` inside `<form>` is not a valid HTML standard. If there is a better way, I will be happy to hear. But I cannot put any code outside the outer form in this case.

```html
    <form action="/action1.php" method="post">
      <label for="fname">First name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
      <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    <div>
    <form action="/action2.php" method="post">
      <label for="fname">Another form first:</label>
      <input type="text" id="fname2" name="fname2"><br><br>
      <label for="lname">Another form last:</label>
      <input type="text" id="lname2" name="lname2"><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    </div>

    </form>
```

Comment: What is the reason nesting one form into another? If you want to submit based on a condition, so you can apply condition in onsubmit event using Javascript.

Comment: @Masood, your proposed solution will have the same problem. Before the form submits to `action2.php`, it will submit to `action1.php`.

Comment: No it will not, if you prevent the submit before your conditional statement.

Comment: @Masood How does your proposed method look like?

Comment: So when you submit the 2nd form you want all the 4 fields to be submitted and with first form only the first 2 fields?

Comment: @Masood, when clicking on the second submit, I want only fields of form 2 are submitted to `action2.php`. I do not want any of fields of form1 be used and I do not want to submit anything to `action1.php`. As if the outer form does not exist.

Comment: So it means the only thing you want is to have a single button for 2 forms?

Comment: I dont care about the outer form. I only want the inner form submits. They submit to different pages. Please do not confuse them. I do not need fields `fname` and `lname`. I only need fields `fname2` and `lname2` to be submitted.

Comment: It is not making sense. If you don't need both forms then why it is there?

Comment: @Masood, it is explained in the question. The outer form is imposed by the template. I do not want it at all. I cannot remove it either. My code is entirely placed inside that form not matter what it is. I am not able to remove the outer form.

Comment: Looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), what is it you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @JonP, No it is not. There is no Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't nest forms, it's invalid and makes no sense.

Use a data attribute on your submit buttons to change the action of the form.

```js
//Get all inputs with the data-action data attribute
document.querySelectorAll("input[data-action]").forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    //Get the form element
    let form = this.closest("form");
    //Set the action from the data attribute
    form.action = this.dataset.action;
    
    //loop top level fieldsets
    form.querySelectorAll("fieldset").forEach(fieldset =>  {
      //if the fieldset doesn't conttain the clicked button
      if(fieldset.querySelector("input[data-action]") != this) {
        //Iterate the inputs and disable them to remove from form submit
        fieldset.querySelectorAll("input, select, textbox").forEach(item => item.disabled = true);
      }
    });
  });
});

//Purely for demo purposes
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.action);
  return  false;
})
```

```html
<form action="/action1.php" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <label for="fname">First name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
    <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" data-action="/action1.php">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="fname">Another form first:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname2" name="fname2"><br><br>
    <label for="lname">Another form last:</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname2" name="lname2"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" data-action="/action2.php">
  </fieldset>

</form>
```

Comment: Just noticed the requirement to have only one set submitted per action. Ideally, you use two separate forms, but if you can't do that I have a solution but I have to get back to you on that as life has got in the way! Basically it will be disabling form elements in the fieldsets that were not clicked

Comment: This solved my problem: `$('#button2').click( function(event) {  event.preventDefault(); ... `. The solution was `preventDefault`. Thanks.

Comment: Just note if you still have nested forms, you still have invalid HTML, and just because it works now doesn't mean it will in the future. Invalid HTML invites unpredicable results.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do can be better achieved using Ajax. Here is an example:

```
 $(#button1).onclick({ 
    $('#fname').val();
    $('#lname).val();
 })
```

Then post the data to through an AJAX.

```
 $(#button2).onclick({ 
     $('#fname2').val();
     $('#lname2).val();
 })
```

Comment: It still submits to `action1.php` not `action2.php`.

Comment: How does sending an object to onclick solves the problem?